# DbContext of a table that has a period in the table name. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, controller

I am trying to create my `dbcontext` for a database to query data from but the tables name is `Table`. `Table` in SQL Server. I did not create the database nor do I have access to do anything with it.

How do you create a `dbcontext` or a class  if you have a period in your table?

```
public DbSet<ADM.INCIDENTS> ADM.INCIDENTS { get; set; }
```

Also, if you are creating your table's class with Entity Framework, do you need to name the class `ADM.INCIDENTS.cs`? If you do, how do you do that?

```
public class ADM.INCIDENTS
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }

    public string Incident{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updated annotation to include schema

Rename the class to whatever you like and use the `Table` annotation

```
public DbSet<ADM_INCIDENTS> ADM_INCIDENTS { get; set; }
```

With:

```
[Table("INCIDENTS", Schema="ADM")]
public class ADM_INCIDENTS
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }

    public string Incident{ get; set; }
}
```

Check [Data Annotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Andres, this works but my SQL Query is trying to pull data as SELECT [i].[ID], [i].[CASE]
FROM [ADM.INCIDENTS] AS [i], How do I get it to look like this: SELECT [i].[ID], [i].[CASE]
FROM [ADM].[INCIDENTS] AS [i] as, SQL will not accept [ADM.INCIDENTS]

Comment: My guess is you have an `ADM` schema? if so, you have to use the overload `[Table("INCIDENTS", Schema="ADM")]`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, the solution proposes works, only you need to know the schema using the query SELECT t.TABLE_TYPE, t.table_schema, t.table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

in order to know the schema you should to use in [Table("INCIDENTS", Schema="ADM")]